# C# Authentication with active directory is not reflecting lastLogon attribute in AD

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory

I am using below code to authenticate user with active directory and it is validating successfully in case of correct credentials, but if I check the attribute "lastLogon" in AD it seems not changed

```
using (LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(domain))
{
    connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
    connection.Credential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

    try
    {
        connection.Bind();
        return "Authentication succeeded.";
    }
    catch (LdapException ex)
    {
        return "Authentication failed: " + ex.Message;
    }
}
```

I tried also to retrieve the attribute using "DirectorySearcher" but it not retrieving the updated date.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you have more than one domain controller. The `lastLogon` attribute is not replicated between DCs. So you will only see the updated value on the DC that you authenticated against.

If your `domain` attribute is just the name of the domain, I believe you can get the name of the DC after you authenticate by looking at `connection.SessionOptions.HostName`. (I *think*)